# No App Check token for request even when app check is not enabled

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-app-check

It seems that only uploading files in Firebase Storage triggers this error for me.
This automatically showed up. Someone said this is a new feature and there's not really much information online. I have tried changing the connected firebase project to my app but to no avail. I have not enabled app check before or for the new firebase project I've connected my app to. I checked on my firebase projects and my application is unregistered for app check as well.

2021-08-09 14:52:20.091 29409-30232/com.capstone.scipy W/NetworkRequest: No App Check token for request.
2021-08-09 14:52:20.095 29409-30232/com.capstone.scipy I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2021-08-09 14:52:20.095 29409-30232/com.capstone.scipy I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2021-08-09 14:52:20.160 29409-30232/com.capstone.scipy W/NetworkRequest: error sending network request POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/scipy-fc3f6.appspot.com/o

Answer (score 1):

The "No App Check token for request" message you are seeing here is just part of the log, which makes sense since you don't have App Check enabled, so no token should be added to the request.

The actual error is just the part at the end: "NetworkRequest: error sending network request POST [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/scipy-fc3f6.appspot.com/o"](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/scipy-fc3f6.appspot.com/o%22) which is usually caused by network problems such as lack of connectivity.  Have you confirmed your device is able to make other network requests?

Source: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/6da8617afe903126afac46ef71b1d857dcfe7ef9/firebase-storage/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/storage/network/NetworkRequest.java#L356

Comment: Hi, yes I do use my device for internet activities as well so far I don't think there is a problem with my internet connection but I will check this out and see if other devices will result in the same error, thanks!